# Adding padding to <li> in CSS is making the content not move with consistent line-height

Tags: css

My predicament is this. I have a list, a simple cart, login, user registration list. I want to move the list up by adding padding. But I cannot with out the list adding line height. What is the way around this? See examples below. This list is in the header.

Before: 
[image]

```css
.content{
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

li {
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 10px;
 direction: right;
 text-align: right; 
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 line-height: 1;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Cart</li>
    <li>Login</li>
    <li>Customer Registration</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After: [image]

Comment: is it that what you really want to do is add margin-bottom to the ul instead of padding-bottom to the li? here's a quick pen: https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/QOMZdK.

Comment: What you want to do..?

Comment: paste your full code

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the padding to the `ul` and not the `li` .

Answer (score 0):

give `margin-top in minus` so it will move upside

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  direction: right;
  text-align: right; 
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Customer Registration</a></li>
</ul
```